# Why the powershell convert my hash table into string block

Tags: powershell, hashtable, key-value

I have a hashtable (`$applications`) that looks like that:

```
Name                                                        Version
----                                                        -------
Adobe Flash Player 19 ActiveX                               19.0.0.226
Enterprise Library 4.0 - May 2008                           4.0.0.0
Entity Framework Designer for Visual Studio 2012 - enu      11.1.21009.00
Fiddler                                                     2.4.0.6
Google Chrome                                               49.0.2623.87
IIS 8.0 Express                                             8.0.1557
```

So I'm trying to exclude some applications from the list and for that I'm using:

```
[array]$excludeApps = "Fiddler","Chrome"
foreach ($excludeApp in $excludeApps){
    $applications = $applications -notlike "*$excludeApp*"
}
```

The result maybe filtered out the exclude list but as not as I expected:

```
@{Name=Adobe Flash Player 19 ActiveX; Version=19.0.0.226}
@{Name=Enterprise Library 4.0 - May 2008; Version=4.0.0.0}
@{Name=Entity Framework Designer for Visual Studio 2012 - enu; Version=11.1.21009.00}
@{Name=IIS 8.0 Express; Version=8.0.1557}
```

I tried to handle those values with `GetEnumerator()` and several syntax of `${applications.Name}` but nothing is worked. I believe that PowerShell detect this list as string.

Any idea how to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use select-object with `-match/-notmatch` Operator.

i.e.:

```
$application = $application | ? { $_.name -notmatch "fiddler" -or $_.name -notmatch "Chrome"}
```

or in the Loop:

```
[array]$excludeApps = "Fiddler","Chrome"
foreach ($excludeApp in $excludeApps){
    $applications = $applications | ? {$_.name -notmatch $excludeApp }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, your data is not a hashtable, but a list of custom objects, probably from importing a CSV. If you want to filter those objects by a list of partial matches (`Fiddler`, `Chrome`) on one of the properties (`Name`) the best approach is to build a regular expression:

```
$excludeApps = 'Fiddler', 'Chrome'
$expr = @($excludeApps | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'
```

and then filter the list with a `-notmatch` condition in a `Where-Object` statement:

```
$applications | Where-Object { $_.Name -notmatch $expr }
```

Comment: This solution will exclude any application that includes those words like "Multi Chrome Converter", " Fiddler on the Roof", etc.

Comment: Which is what the OP was asking.